# Identify a movie about an autistic person stopping doomsday

Tags: story-identification, movie, apocalypse

This movie is about meteor/space object hitting Earth. This is what I remember about the movie:

- This movie is not very old. I think it came out perhaps around early 
  2000s.
- There's a scene in which a woman scientist states that all
  the paper in the world is not enough to make calculations about the
  meteor/space object.
- There's a scene in which an autistic man
  calls the leader of the scientists. He says that he already did the
  some sort of    calculation/formula to stop the doomsday. The leader
  does not believe    him, but the autistic man mentions some of his
  calculations or a passcode/username of the leader project (not really sure), and then    the leader believes him.

It'd be great if the title is identified. I'd like to watch it again.

Comment: Are you sure about it being from the early 2000s? That is well into the computer age, and it is unlikely anyone would comment on how much paper is required for the calculations.

Comment: the woman scientist say that because she prefer do the calculation manually and all the paper in the world is not enough to do it. and yeah there are computer and other things too.

Comment: I think this was a scyfy movie - the plot sounds familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it was *early* 2000s? It might be [Quantum Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Apocalypse), which has a very similar plot - the autistic man has the solution but of course is not initially believed but saves the day at the end.

> uring routine administration at the Lyndon B. Johnson Space Center, Dr. Rhodes discovers that a comet has suddenly veered off its orbit and smashed into Mars. The explosion causes debris to travel towards Earth with the possibility of causing an extinction level event. At Ben Marshall's house, Ben refuses to give his son, Leo, a ride as he complained his own car smelled of mildew. However, Ben drives Leo to school and discovers Leo is in love with a fellow student, Lindsey. Leo is chatting with Lindsey when her ex-boyfriend, Sean, gives them threatening looks.
>
> Terry, Ben's autistic brother, refuses to let Samantha, Ben's daughter, take the school bus, which is having mechanical problems. Lynne, Ben's wife, comes home to discover that and drives Samantha to school. They are caught in a traffic jam caused by an incident involving the school bus.

....

> Along the way to Houston, Ben and Terry encounter a broken down vehicle. While trying to help, Ben is attacked, but Terry takes out the attacker, and they continue on their way. Ben suffers a heart attack, but they manage to reach the Space Center. They gain entry because Terry knows Dr. Rhodes's verbal password. Terry manages to convince Dr. Rhodes of his calculations, which was shown to be accurate. Ben dies from his heart attack.

Comment: Hmm.. i need to rewatch it first. Especially about the scene i remember. About the release year, i'm pretty sure i watched it long time ago, around 2000's but maybe it's my memory mistake. Thanks for your answer.